# How to search specific column within range in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hello and thank you for taking the time to read this and thank you for any advice!

I'm using VBA to search for the first value within an array which is greater than a value specified elsewhere in a cell, and outputting the column and row number to new cells.

The code I am using is:

```
Sub A()

Dim rng As Range
Dim v As Variant
Dim colnum As Long
Dim row As Long

Set rng = Range("B2:BT72")
v = Sheets("WIP").Range("AC76").Value
For Each cll In rng
If cll.Value > v Then
    colnum = cll.Column
    row = cll.row
Exit For
End If
Next
Sheets("WIP").Range("AF76").Value = colnum + 25
Sheets("WIP").Range("AG76").Value = row + 25

End Sub
```

And that works fine. However I now need to only search a certain column and just output the row value. The column I need to search is also specified in a specific cell. I've modified the code to:

```
Sub B()

Dim rng As Range
Dim v As Variant
Dim x As Variant
Dim row As Long

Set rng = Range("A2:BT72")
v = Sheets("WIP").Range("AC77").Value
x = Sheets("WIP").Range("AF77").Value

For Each cell In rng.Columns(x - 25)
If cell.Value > v Then
    row = cell.row
Exit For
End If
Next
Sheets("WIP").Range("AG77").Value = row + 25

End Sub
```

This time I'm getting an error message type mismatch on the line "If cell.value > V Then"
Can anybody spot why?

Thanks

Comment: The cell could be empty or of a different type of value. Add a check for `IsEmpty(cell.Value)` and possibly `IsNumeric(cell.Value)`.

Comment: Hey Peter, thanks for the comment! The cells not empty and is a numeric value so don't think that's the problem!

Comment: Try putting a temporary debug statement in your loop to check your values, perhaps `Debug.Print "cell=" & cell.Value & ", v=" & v`. Clearly some type mismatch is occurring.

Comment: Just a quick observation: Avoid using reserved terms like "row" and "column" as variable names.  It can create confusion in your code.  Using variable names that are somewhat descriptive can help to provide you with a bit of self-documentation.  For example using "foundRow" instead of "row" makes it very clear to anyone else looking at your code what the variable's purpose is.

Comment: If v is numeric, then declare it as such, instead of using "Variant".  By using "Variant", you never know what your datatype will be.  Also, as @PeterT said, you should still check to confirm that the value in Sheets("WIP").Range("AC77").Value is truly a numeric value.  Since you can have values that appear to be numeric, but are actually text, checking for the validity of the data is critical.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Frank, I am very new to VBA so it is all very appreciated! I have put the data in to that cell myself though and have double checked, definitely numeric!

Comment: You can type values into a cell and it can show a number, but still be formatted as text. If you don't want to perform a check in your VBA code, then you can visually check by looking at the *Number* group on the *Home* ribbon menu. That will show the format of the cell. Bottom line is though, we're not getting enough information about your situation to help you solve the problem. Did you try the `Debug` statements and was it helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The '.Cells' property needs to be specified for the range object in the second example:

```
Sub B()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim row As Long

    Set rng = Range("A2:BT72")
    v = Sheets("WIP").Range("AC77").Value
    x = Sheets("WIP").Range("AF77").Value

    For Each cell In rng.Columns(x - 25).Cells
        If cell.Value > v Then
            row = cell.row
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    Sheets("WIP").Range("AG77").Value = row + 25

End Sub
```